# Включил layers.* в about:config, что означают выводимые FPS и цвет границ слоев?

Tags: css3, firefox, анимация, производительность

Сейчас у меня `Mozilla Developer Edition 42.0a2 (2015-09-08)`, не знаю с какой версии появились эти свойства, но все же.

1. `layers.acceleration.draw-fps` добавляет три цифровых блока в левый верхний угол окна. Первый блок отвечает за `fps`, это я понял, а что показывают остальные 2, я не смог пока сообразить. Что они значат?
2. `layers.draw-borders` позволяет браузеру выделять слои, грузящиеся в GPU, в документе, на сколько я знаю. Браузер выделяет их зеленым цветом, однако, бывают случаи, порой замечал на других сайтах, довольно редко правда, когда он это делает синим или даже красным цветом, что это значит?

Comment: Если покопаться по вопросу (1), можно найти в баг-трекере Mozilla обсуждения о том, что к практическому применению счётчик непригоден. Но я ради интереса включил их у себя, первые два счётчика показывают FPS, а третий всегда на 099, не знаю...

Comment: @D-side, когда на странице происходит анимация какая-либо, первая цифра практически всегда верна, удобно смотреть, не включая профайлер. Вот [здесь](http://codepen.io/johnblazek/full/nceyw/), например, можно для примера сравнить. Второй счетчик другой `fps`, может это `CPU` и `GPU`... А третий у меня всегда `100`.

Comment: Ну, мне тоже нечем это подтвердить, но первые два числа у меня почти не отличаются. [У себя](http://dside.ru/) на курсоре сверху я получаю 60, 61, 99, потом анимация курсора кончается и первые два падают до 1, третье по-прежнему на 99. Если у вас второе число ведёт себя существенно иначе, то у вас больше шансов понять, что оно означает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `layers.acceleration.draw-fps` [выводит 3 числа](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/9ed17db42e3e46f1c712e4dffd62d54e915e0fac/gfx/layers/composite/FPSCounter.cpp#l442): compositions/sec, transactions/sec, [fill ratio %](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=915342).

Чтобы понять, что они означают, надо разбираться в архитектуре графической подсистемы Firefox. Не могу сказать, что я эксперт в этой области, но в частности из [Gecko overview: compositing](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Overview#Compositing) и вот этих двух постов: [1](http://chrislord.net/index.php/2011/07/25/shadow-layers-and-learning-by-failing/), [2](https://benoitgirard.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/visual-warning-for-slow-b2g-transaction-landed/), у меня сложилось такое понимание:

- Все окно/страница разбивается на "слои" (layers): блоки, нарисовав которые друг поверх друга, можно получить искомое изображение. Например, "прикрепленная" фоновая картинка, текст, изображение в `<canvas>` и видео могут каждый быть в своем слое.
- Прорисовка происходит в два этапа: сначала обновляется содержимое "слоев", потом слои складываются (это называется "compositing") в итоговое изображение на экране (в идеале - весьма эффективно, с использованием GPU).
- Эти два этапа выполняются в разных потоках (с т.н. OMTC - off-main-thread compositing) или даже в разных процессах (отрисовка слоев - в "content" процессе конкретной страницы, финальный compositing в основном процессе).

Это позволяет в ситуациях, когда страница притормаживает (из-за JavaScript или просто когда обновление слоев получается тяжелым) показывать лучший responsiveness, т.е. не тормозить слишком сильно с точки зрения пользователя. Например, прокрутка (scrolling) возможна за счет сдвига слоев, показать следующий кадр видео можно не дожидаясь пока отработает JS на странице.

Так вот,

- Первое число - это сколько раз выполнился compositing, т.е. обновилась картинка на экране. Это то, что логично назвать FPS.
- Второе число, как я понимаю, - это сколько раз (в секунду) обновились "слои".
- (Про третье - fill ratio - кроме того, что написано по ссылке в самом начале ответа, ничего сказать не могу.)

Например, когда я на OS X проигрываю HTML5 видео в YouTube, первое число = 60FPS, второе 0. А если навести мышь на видео так, чтобы начали отображаться элементы управления видео, второе сразу становится >0.

Доступность и интерпретация этих чисел зависит от платформы, версии и настроек, на полноту ответа не претендую. Кстати, [тут](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1184893) утверждается, что под Windows числа могут быть неверными.

2) `layers.draw-borders` рисуются вроде как в [Compositor::DrawDiagnosticsInternal](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/9ed17db42e3e46f1c712e4dffd62d54e915e0fac/gfx/layers/Compositor.cpp#125). Если я правильно читаю, то разными цветами обозначаются layer-ы разных типов, красным и голубым - картинки и одноцветные слои, соответственно.